# how to print missing rows of a dataframe versus another

Tags: python, dataframe, comparison, missing-data

I want to find rows that are missing in the first dataframe.

So I have two dataframes:

```
data1 = {'first_column':  ['2', '3'],
        'second_column': ['2', '2'],
       'third_column':['2', '1'],
        }

data2 = {'first_column':  ['2', '2'],
        'second_column': ['2', '2'],
       'third_column':['2', '2'],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

expected output:

```
first_column second_column third_column
           3             2            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If I understood your requirement properly then**, One way to do it using `drop_duplicates` and `merge`. Finally, pick only the `left_only`.

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'first_column':  ['2', '3'],
        'second_column': ['2', '2'],
       'third_column':['2', '1'],
        }

data2 = {'first_column':  ['2', '2'],
        'second_column': ['2', '2'],
       'third_column':['2', '2'],
        }

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df = df1.drop_duplicates().merge(df2.drop_duplicates(), on=df2.columns.to_list(), 
                   how='left', indicator=True)
final_result = df.loc[df._merge=='left_only',df.columns!='_merge']
print(final_result.reset_index())
```

**Output:**

```
  first_column second_column third_column
0            3             2            1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and use it to select the `left_only` rows:

```
out = (df1
 .merge(df2, how='left', indicator=True)
 .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')]
)
```

*NB. if you have duplicates in `df2`, use `df2.drop_duplicates()` in the merge to improve efficiency like shown by @AlwaysSunny.*

output:

```
  first_column second_column third_column
2            3             2            1
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

```
# form a key by combining the column values  in each row and assign to keys_list
keys_list= df2.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.values), axis=1).to_list()

# form a key in DF1 and check for non-existence in df2
df1[df1.apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.values) not in keys_list  , axis=1)]
```

```
first_column    second_column   third_column
1   3   2   1
```